# AngularJS : Render controller without waiting factory variable to be intialized first

Tags: angularjs

First, I'm new to angularjs. I've create a factory to handle most of my data named "store". Here is an example:

```
app.factory('store', function ($rootScope, $http, $q, api) {
var data = {};

return {
    
    setData: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: api.getData()
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // handle data
            $rootScope.broadcast('store:data', data);
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function errorCallback(reponse) {
            // do stuff
            deferred.reject();
        });
    },
    
    getData: function () {
        return data;
    },
    
    addData: function (newData) {
        // do stuff
    },
    
    editData: function (newData) {
        // do stuff
    },
    
    deleteData: function (newData) {
        // do stuff
    }
    
  };
});
```

I'm initializing this data inside my app.run function. BUT, I don't want my app to wait my data to be initialized first to render the controller. I want it to be rendered first and wait for updating when the data is initialized.

```
    store.setData()
    .then(function (response) {
        // do stuff
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        // do stuff
    });
```

Here is how I'm getting the data updated inside my controller to be rendered

```
    $scope.data = store.getData();

    $rootScope.$on('store:data', function (event, data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    })
```

SO my problem is that I don't want to wait my data to be initialized to render my controller.
Is there a solution to this problem ?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT** May 20 2021

Btw if what I'm doing is wrong and there is better things to do, I'm open to any suggestions ! Thnx

**EDIT** June 9 2021

Now I'm using $resource, but I don't know how can I get the new version of my list of data when I add new element to it.

```
agents: $resource(
        api.getAgents(),
        {},
        {
            get: {method: 'GET', isArray: false, cache: true},
            add: {method: 'POST', url: api.addAgent(), hasBody: true},
            edit: {method: 'PUT', url: api.editAgent(), params: {agentId: '@id'}, hasBody: true},
            delete: {method: 'DELETE', url: api.deleteAgent(), params: {agentId: '@id'}},
        }
    ),
```

Waiting for an answer. Thank you vm !

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options you can consider, but first a note on best practices in AngularJS and JavaScript: avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns). The `$http` service returns a promise. You should work with that rather than creating a new promise with `$q.defer`.

The first option is to change the `getData` method to return a promise instead of the actual data. It is a good idea to always design your data retrieval services to return promises, even when you intend to pre-retrieve and cache the data. This provides the cleanest way to ensure that the data is available before you try to use it. In your example, you should be able to internally cache the promise rather than the data. So your code would change to something like this:

```
app.factory('store', function ($rootScope, $http, api) {
    var dataPromise;

    return {
        
        setData: function () {
            dataPromise = $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: api.getData()
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    // handle data
                    $rootScope.broadcast('store:data', data);
                }, function errorCallback(reponse) {
                    // do stuff
                });
        },
        
        getData: function () {
            if (!dataPromise) {
                this.setData();
            }
            return dataPromise;
        },
        
        // etc.
    };
}
```

You will of course have to change the code that calls the `getData` method to work with the promise instead of working directly with the data.

Another option is to use an [AngularJS Resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). This feature works very much like your original intent by returning an instance of an object that at some point will get populated with data. It takes advantage of the AngularJS change detection to render the data once it becomes available. Resources also have the ability to cache responses internally so that the call to the server is only made once. Rewriting your service as a resource would look something like this:

```
app.factory('store', function ($rootScope, $resource, api) {

    return $resource(
        api.getData(),  // the base URL
        {},             // parameter defaults
        {               // actions
            getData: {
                method: 'GET',
                cache: true
            },
            // etc.
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jack A., thank you for the answer. I wanted to know how can I get my data updated when I've added a new element to it ? (data is an object array for example). Waiting for a reply. Ty !